# Show that if $Q$ is orthogonal, then $Q^{-1}$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonality

I know this should be basic and easy, but as I'm going through my book, I just can't seem to get this to work.

Show that if $Q$ is orthogonal, then $Q^{-1}$ is orthogonal?

I assume that multiplication of orthogonal vectors are also orthogonal as well. For example:

$Q_{1}Q_{2} = [Orthogonal Matrix]$

Comment: Do you know what is an orthogonal matrix? What have you tried?

Comment: Note that for an orthogonal matrix $Q^{-1} = Q^T$, by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ (Q^{-1})(Q^{-1})^\intercal = (Q^{-1})(Q^\intercal)^{-1} = (Q^\intercal Q)^{-1} = I^{-1} = I
$$
where the identities $(MN)^{-1} = N^{-1}M^{-1}, (M^\intercal)^{-1} = (M^{-1})^\intercal$ are used.

Comment: And the identity $Q^TQ = QQ^T$. :)

Comment: A small error after the second `=`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. It is fixed.

Comment: So I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$Q^{-1}={}^{\mathrm t}Q\implies(Q^{-1})^{-1}=({}^{\mathrm t}Q)^{-1}={}^{\mathrm t}(Q^{-1}).$$